# Cloudinary upload image from Django admin panel from two or more databases

Tags: django, django-models, cloudinary

everyone. I decide to use Cloudinary for storing images.
This is my model field with image:

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar/', default='avatar/default.png', blank=True)
```

All works fine for me, but I have one little issue.
When I uploaded the image from admin panel, cloudinary upload it to my cloudinary folder 'avatar' with some modified name, for example: 'july2022_kda4th' or 'july2022_aidkdk'
But when I uploaded this image from admin panel of another database (production), cloudinary upload the image with another name. So, I have two similar images in cloudinary. It's not convenient.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you don't supply a public_id in the upload API call, a random string is assigned to the asset. You can read more here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#public_id.

It sounds like you want to use the asset filename as the public_id so what you can do is:

- In forms set `use_filename=true` and `unique_filename=false` as described in this [link](https://%5Bhttps://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload#django_forms_and_models%5D)

OR if above is not working you can

1. Create an upload preset https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_presets
2. Enable `Use filename or externally defined Public ID:` option
3. Disable `Unique filename:`
4. Set this preset as the default upload API/UI (https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_presets#default_upload_presets) or include this `upload_preset` in your upload call

Comment: hi, Tom, thank you for the answer. I didn't understand what about you wrote until I went to the cloudinary settings. After that I understood all. Thank you, it's worked now!